# Ruby on Rails - Getting datatables to load 100% of time and not just on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My ruby on rails application has datatables; however, they only appear after the user goes to the page and refreshes once. It doesn't appear initially when then they go to the page.

Here is the javascript that's run prior to the page loading (because it's before the html content);

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    return $('#items').dataTable();
  });

}).call(this);
```

However, I thought using this may help, but it didn't:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#items').dataTable();
});
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this goal easily?

Comment: What do your view and controller look like? Is the Javascript in a separate .js file or in your view code? Does the page render fine without calling .dataTable()?

Comment: The javascript is in the assets/whatever.js file and the page also lodas fine without calling .dataTable(). The content in the examples above are located in the js file.

Comment: Try to do an "inspect element" after the page loads for the first time and see if there's any warning/error showing up.

Comment: A friend suggested that to me too, and no warnings or anything popped up in the console. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever this happens to me, I find the culprit is usually Turbolinks.  You should be able to use one of two options to get around it.

The first is this workaround for your js which has been passed around SO quite a bit.

```
var ready;

ready = function(){
  //your js scripts go here
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Or you can update the link_to helper you are using to get to this page to skip turbolinks when loading the page:

```
<%= link_to "Where you're going", add_product_path, data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
```